# Ice machine in the freezer works intermittently

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker, freezer

[image]I have a GE freezer/fridge unit and the ice machine stops working intermittently. Usually after I take the ice bucket out and reinsert it, the machine gets back on track, but about 2 months ago it stopped working for over a week. Last time, I even replaced the water filter in case that mattered, but two days later still nothing, then, while I was literally writing a stackexchange question on what I should do (this is not a joke), presto I heard a "thunk" and the ice machine has worked ever since.

Now the machine has started acting up again and so I am wondering if anyone has any ideas of what I should do. The way I figure it, the ice machine will turn "on" when that tongue thing is extended out instead of being below the ice tray. It looks like there is a slow drip from the ice tray to the tongue and my guess is that maybe that is stopping the tongue from swinging out after enough ice has built up. Anyway I removed the ice from the tongue and the machine started working again only to stop after a couple cycles.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what can be done here or how this machine works if my assessment above is wrong? Below is an image of the ice machine with the tongue extended out.

[image: Ice Machine and model number]

Comment: Personally, I'm a fan of removing it, taking back the freezer space it wastes, and putting a few ice trays in...they are very reliable, and I have more freezer space that way.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  The metal ones with the lever are always fun.  Think I still have one or two lying around.

Comment: it likely is the fill sensor. you are getting false-positives, it thinks there's too much ice when there's not.  I would try adding WD40 or silicone grease on any part it touches that moves. Also swing the arm/tounge it's full range semi-violently to loosen up anything that might have gotten jammed in a hinge or pinch point.

Comment: Model of fridge?

Comment: Added image of the model number: GSHL5KGXBCLS